# Medium Voltage Synchronous Motor Protection

Tags: surge-protection, synchronous-motor

How is the wound field of a medium voltage synchronous motor protected from voltage surges? We do know that the stator is protected from surges by either one of the following:
1. RC Snubber Circuit
2. Surge Capacitor
3. A surge arrester in combition with point 1 or 2 above.

Comment: If this is homework then you need to show your effort at answering the question. If not then what is the context for the question? Please use the edit link below your question to add in the missing details.

Comment: If you are not satisfied with the answers to your question, post comments there, do not post a duplicate of the same question. You can also revise the original question to make it more specific.

Comment: Hi this question is clear and I have finally found the answer. For synchronous motors surge protection is applied on the stator and on the field winding( for wound field synchronous motors). The surge protection that is applied on the synchronous motor stator is essentially the same that is applied on the stator of the inducion motors i.e RC Snubber or Surge Capacitors or a combination of an RC snubber with a surge arrester or a combination of a surge capacitor with a surge arrester. A field discharge capacitor is used on a synchronous motor to protect the field windings from surges.